# xlsxwriter - changing font in comment

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to change comment formatting in xlsxwriter - write_comment()
I would like to have monospaced font there like 'Courier New' and I have no idea how to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @alecxe: Finally feature available, see my solution below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, there's a commit after my change request on github for this feature request. 
This is the commit: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/commit/d49552c9c07e30900a120eca2f73226e682c31f2, i.e. you have to use the latest Master release.

Then you can use:

```
worksheet.write_comment('B2', 'Some text', {'font_name': 'MS Gothic', 'font_family': 3, 'font_size': 10})
```

Comment: New info: Now it's in the official RELEASE_1.1.1

Answer (score 3):

According to [`Working with Cell Comments`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_cell_comments.html) documentation paragraph, `xlsxwriter` doesn't let you change the default font used in comments. The only options you can change are:

```
author
visible
x_scale
width
y_scale
height
color
start_cell
start_row
start_col
x_offset
y_offset
```

Created a github issue at `xlsxwriter` issue tracker, was marked as "feature request" by @jmcnamara:

- [Changing font in cell comments](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/201)